# Can I make border-bottom look narrower than <div>?

Tags: html, css

On the main menu, if a menu link is active, there is a border on the bottom. It works fine. I have the following CSS:

```
.active {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #888;
}
```

Currently the `border-bottom` is as wide as the text inside the list item. But I would like to make it much narrower. Is that possible?

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you could always try utilising the :after pseudo element?

Comment: Yeah it's not possible, you can work with the `:after` pseudo-element. You can also animate 'underlines' & other cool stuff http://codepen.io/Webketje/pen/rhjpl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the pseudo-element `:after` to achieve that, as I don't think it's possible to make the border narrower than the element's width.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6QfNs/

Comment: [This is a better result](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/AAGbf/). You coud just use `margin: 0 auto;` to adjust `.active:after` to center.

Answer (score 4):

A border can't be narrower than the element it is set on. So you can't achieve your aim with a border.

**BUT**

You can use a pseudo element, set the border on it and give it the desired width :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/eS9w2/)**

*CSS :*

```
.active:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #888;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The technique of using pseudo-elements is very familar and well-known in solving the problems of this kind. However I would like to introduce another way using `linear-gradient` background, just a share for every one:

```
/* span is your menu item here */
span {
  font-size:20px;
  padding:4px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
span:hover {
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) no-repeat;
  background-size:60% 4px;
  background-position:center bottom;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/G5ek4/)